# C++ - Can I simulate (the overloading of) Binary Operators such as it is possible in C#?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am a (re) beginner in C++. I tried if I could define a binary `operator +` but that only gave me a compiler error in `g++`. In `C#` they are independent of classes. In C++, like in Ruby, they are obviously not, such that they are unary.

Now in order for an internal grammar production representation I would need a **binary** `operator +` to create symbol lists, where the first element is a `char*` array (?) [that is, I don't know if the *between* of two `\"` is a literal in c++]

example 1:

```
list = "(" + elements + ")"
```

such that the binary `operator +` could create Terminal Symbols from the `open/close parens`

example 2:

```
std::vector<Symbol>* operator+ (char* string, Symbol sym) {
  return OpPlus(Terminal(string), sym);
}
```

**Can I simulate binary operators in C++ ?**

Yours

von Spotz

Comment: It helps a lot to explain *exactly* what error you got.

Comment: `"("` is `const char[2]` which might decay to `const char*`, but not to `char*`.

Comment: pointer on `std::vector` is always strange...